# Misplaced \omit when using \multicolumn within \multirow

Tags: tables, xetex, multirow, multicolumn

I'm trying to put a \multicolumn within a \multirow environment in the following manner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{.03\textwidth}|p{.73\textwidth}|p{.03\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|}
        Test1 & Test2 & Test3 &
        \multirow{1}{*}{\multicolumn{1}{m{\linewidth}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
        {example-image}}}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For clarification, I have multiple rows in the table (6) and the multirow spans those 6 rows. The inner multicolumn is so that the image is centered within the multirow. However, I get the error:

```
Misplaced \Omit
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

### Update:

See Christian's answer for fixing the error. But latex was still having trouble centering the picture vertically when one of the rows was had multi line text. As a workaround, I increased the number of rows the multirow is spanning even though there are actually 6. This is admittedly an ugly hack and one I'm not particularly happy with, but it works for now. If anyone has any better solution, I'm open to suggestions.

### Update 2:

Ok so update 2. See Christian's revised solution and comments for two possible ways to get around this problem. Thanks Christian for all the help!

Comment: You have to switch the `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` statements. `\multicolumn` outside, then `\multirow` inside. I suppose, the lines with 'Test1' etc. should be in multirow(s) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, this is what you meant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{.03\textwidth}|p{.73\textwidth}|p{.03\textwidth}|p{.15\textwidth}|}
          Test1 & Test2 & Test3 & 
    \multicolumn{1}{m{\linewidth}}{\multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}}% End of multirow
          }% End of multicolumn
      \\ % End of the first row 
       Line2  & & &\\
       Line3  & & & \\
       Line4  & & & \\
       Line5  & & & \\
       Line6  & & & \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Another version with vertical centered content, which uses the `makecell` package and the `\multirowcell` command, which allows for a vertical shift
of the content in the tabular cell (First optional parameter of `\multirowcell`), which is set to `-2pt` by me since I have the impression, this aligns correctly, however, it has to be revised if the size/scaling of the image changes. It is a 'hack' as well, but perhaps it is better than adding extra rows.

```
 \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{multirow,makecell}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{mwe}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{.1\textwidth}|p{.2\textwidth}|p{.1\textwidth}|p{.15  \textwidth}|}
          \hline
          Test1 & Test2 & Test3 & 
           \multirowcell{6}[-2pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}%
           }% End of multirowcell
          \\
           Line2  & & & \\
           Line3  & & & \\
           Line4  & & & \\
           Line5  & & & \\
           Line6  & & & \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

I added the `\hline` in order to check to the alignment and reduced the width of columns. Please roll back as you desire.

[image: Screenshot multirow cell]

By the way, the `\multirow` command allows also a vertical shifting, but I have not tried that so far.

Comment: This fixes the error, but now I have the problem that latex centers the picture in only one row, whereas I want it to be centered across all six rows. Plus if I specify column borders, they are applied to only one row, whereas they should be applied to all six rows. Does that make sense?

Comment: @KG: You have to change the `1` as an argument to `\multirow` to `6`. Additionally, I added five 'dummy' lines. Sorry, I forgot that you wanted to have six rows in my answer initially.

Comment: yes I am aware of that. I have already done that. Let me test your code and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok I did a little bit more digging around and have figured out that the problem is when text in a row spans multiple lines. Latex seems to center the figure assuming single-line rows. The alignment is thrown off when one or more of the rows has multiline. Any solution for that?

Comment: Not at the moment, sorry, for I am writing on a tablet and have no access to `LaTeX` at the moment. What about a `parbox` containing your figure, alignment can be done within?

Comment: Tried `parbox`. Doesn't seem to work since inner-position requires height to be specified as well. Thanks for all your help. I've figured out a workaround for now. If you get time to provide a better solution, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I try tomorrow to get a solution

Comment: @KG: I changed the code a little bit, after reading and provided another solution, please have a look on the second version.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Christian. Qualitatively is there any difference between my hack and yours? In both cases it seems I'd have to change the values if the quantity of text changes. Why prefer one over the other?

Comment: Ok so thanks for the hint. Reading through the ``multirow`` documentation, I found that they actually mention this problem, and the ``fixup``parameter is the recommended way to deal with it. I borrowed your idea and added a negative ``fixup`` value and got the correct alignment. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @KG: No, I do not think that there is a real difference between our solutions. I found similar statements about the fixing in other documentations. Layouting tables is a complex procedure for `LaTeX`, perhaps this is a feature of the core.